# Displaying radio button in elements in Shiny in a horizontal order instead of default vertical view

Tags: r, user-interface, widget, radio-button, shiny

I'm working on a Shiny app that enables folk to browse some time series data. I have a number of widgets that enable people to select variables and type of analysis. In between, I have a modest `radioButton` mechanism that allows users to select time series for some variables:

```
radioButtons("radio_year_select","Year", c("1999" = "1999", "2001" = "2001"))),
```

The code generates a simple widget:

[image: widget - years]

In the context of this particular application, I would like to have the options presented in a horizontal order, like that:

> *Year:*      [X]**1999**              [   ]**2001**

Is there a simple way to achieve that?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Add `inline=TRUE`

```
radioButtons("radio_year_select","Year", c("1999" = "1999", "2001" = "2001"), inline=T)
```