# R shinymaterial display radio buttons inline

Tags: shiny

In R Shiny, the radio buttons can be shown horizontally using option `inline = TRUE` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974588/displaying-radio-button-in-elements-in-shiny-in-a-horizontal-order-instead-of-de), is there a way to do this with `material_radio_button` using the [shinymaterial package](https://ericrayanderson.github.io/shinymaterial/)?

I have tried using `inline = TRUE` and get error `unused argument (inline = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinymaterial)

ui <- fluidPage(
  material_radio_button(
    input_id = "example_radio_button",
    label = "Radio Button",
    choices = c(
      "Cake" = "c",
      "Pie" = "p",
      "Brownie" = "b"
    ),
    color = "#ef5350"
  ),

  tagList(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(
        "#example_radio_button {display: flex;}"
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You can try `display: flex;` or replace `flex` with `-webkit-box`, `-webkit-inline-box`, or `inline-flex`.

**Update**

This might look better:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinymaterial)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h5(tags$b('Radio Button')),
  material_radio_button(
    input_id = "example_radio_button",
    label = "",
    choices = c(
      "Cake" = "c",
      "Pie" = "p",
      "Brownie" = "b"
    ),
    color = "#ef5350"
  ),

  tagList(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(
        "#example_radio_button {display: flex;}
        input[type=radio] {margin-left: 10px;}"
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```