# Rendering infoBox by selecting radio button

Tags: r, shiny

I am not able to build a code which will render 'infoBox' while selecting radio buttons.

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- shinyUI(
fluidPage(h5("D"),
mainPanel(
tabsetPanel(type = "tab",
tabPanel(
fluidRow(
radioButtons("rad", "Select box",
               c("1" = "norm",
                 "2" = "unif")

norm <- box(h3("Super")
infoBox("10", "ab", width = 6)
infoBox("11", "bc", width = 6)
),
unif <-box(h3("Duper")
infoBox("20", "cd", width = 6)
infoBox("21", "de", width = 6)
)))))))

infoBoxOutput("loc")

server <- shinySever(function(input, output){
output$loc <- {(
renderinfoBox(input$rad)
)}
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am getting error :
**Error in if (inline) { : argument is not interpretable as logical**
[image: sample respresent]

[image: sample representation]

Comment: Your given example doesn't work due to missing/messed up parentheses in UI part.

Comment: I messed up with code that why seeking help from someone.

Comment: Can anybody help me out in coding to get the output like shown in sample pics?

Comment: Problem is that I can't reproduce error that you're getting

Comment: > runApp('C:/Users/sankar_a/Desktop/radiobutton infobox.R')
Warning in if (inline) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Error in if (inline) { : argument is not interpretable as logical

Comment: this what I am getting while running the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(h5("D"),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(type = "tab",
                                      tabPanel("T1"),
                                      tabPanel(
                                        "T2",
                                        fluidRow(radioButtons(
                                          "rad",
                                          "Select box",
                                          c("1" = "norm", "2" = "unif")
                                        ),
                                        infoBoxOutput("loc"))
                                      ))
                        )))



server <- function(input, output) {
  output$loc <- renderInfoBox({
    if (input$rad == "norm") {
      box(h3("Super"),
          infoBox("10", "ab", width = 6),
          infoBox("11", "bc", width = 6))
    } else{
      if (input$rad == "unif") {
        box(h3("Duper"),
            infoBox("20", "cd", width = 6),
            infoBox("21", "de", width = 6))
      }
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Now radio buttons are in vertical sequence. Can it be in horizontal sequence ?

Comment: Can all radio buttons display in a single row ?

Comment: Yes, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974588/displaying-radio-button-in-elements-in-shiny-in-a-horizontal-order-instead-of-de